# php - Why foreach only runs once?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I really was searching quite some time but I do not know what to change. My php code gets an array and I want it to insert into a mysqlDB. Problem is that it only runs the foreach loop once. Why is it not running?

```
public function insert_tags($projektID, $tags) {
    print_r($tags);
    foreach($tags as $tag)
        $this->db->set('name', $tag);
        $this->db->insert('tags');
        echo $tag;
        $tag_ID = $this->db->insert_id();
        echo $tag_ID;
        if ($tag_ID != 0) {
            $this->db->set('id', $projektID);
            $this->db->set('tag_ID', $tag_ID);
            $this->db->insert('hat_tags');
        }
}
```

It echos:

```
Array
(
    [0] => tag1
    [1] => tag2
)
tag2 147
```

No further error. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose them in {} brackets otherwise it will loop the first line next to it. Use the code below

```
public function insert_tags($projektID, $tags) {
    print_r($tags);
    foreach($tags as $tag){
        $this->db->set('name', $tag);
        $this->db->insert('tags');
        echo $tag;
        $tag_ID = $this->db->insert_id();
        echo $tag_ID;
        if ($tag_ID != 0) {
            $this->db->set('id', $projektID);
            $this->db->set('tag_ID', $tag_ID);
            $this->db->insert('hat_tags');
        }
    }

}
```

Or you can use it with endforeach

```
public function insert_tags($projektID, $tags) {
    print_r($tags);
    foreach($tags as $tag):
        $this->db->set('name', $tag);
        $this->db->insert('tags');
        echo $tag;
        $tag_ID = $this->db->insert_id();
        echo $tag_ID;
        if ($tag_ID != 0) {
            $this->db->set('id', $projektID);
            $this->db->set('tag_ID', $tag_ID);
            $this->db->insert('hat_tags');
        }
    endforeach;

}
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 4):

foreach loop needs to be enclosed in braces {} otherwise it will loop only one line after the foreach statement

Comment: Doesn´t need to be enclosed in braces actually, you can use an alternative syntax like: `foreach(): endforeach;`